# Vectorized range checking in Matlab

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, vector, vectorization

In trying to port an algorithm from C# to Matlab I found that Matlab is inefficient at running for loops. As such I want to vectorize the algorithm.

I have following inputs:

lowrange:

```
[ 00 10 20 30 40 50 ... ]
```

highrange:

```
[ 10 20 30 40 50 60 ... ]
```

These arrays are equal in length.

I now have a third array `Values` (which could be any length) and for this array I want to count the  occurrences of `Values` elements between `lowerange(i)` and `highrange(i)` (You can see I'm coming from a for loop).

The output should be an array of length lowrange/highrange.

So with the above arrays and input `LineData`:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 6 11 12 16 31 34 45 ]
```

I expect to get:

```
[ 05 03 00 02 01 00 ...  ]
```

I tried the (for me) obvious thing:

```
LineData(LineData < PixelEnd & LineData > PixelStart)
```

But that doesn't work because it just checks LineData on an element by element way. It does not try to apply the comparison over all values in `LineData`.

Unfortunately, I cannot come up with anything else since I'm not yet used to think in a Matlab 'vector' way, let alone knowing all applicable instructions from memory.

Comment: What if any element from `Values` falls on the boundary like `10` or `20`? Also, are the intervals between elements of `lowrange` and `highrange` the same, which is `10` in the given data.

Comment: @Divakar good points... My data is generated by a physical process so it might occur that something falls exactly on the boundary. However, I assume that hits suggested in one of the answers would have provisions for such an event (but indeed, I would need to check what they are). On the other hand, yes the interval would always be constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are looking to do a basic histogram with given edges, you can use Matlabs built-in function histc:

```
values = [ 1 2 3 4 6 11 12 16 31 34 45 ];
edges = 0:10:60;
histc(values, edges)

ans =

 5     3     0     2     1     0     0
```

Comment: I think it would be fast enough! Smart move to see `histc` would fit in here. +1

Answer (score 2):

For ranges with identical intervals and starting from `0`, here's a `bsxfun` based counting approach -

```
LineData = [ 1 2 3 4 6 11 12 16 31 34 45 ] %// Input

interval = 10; %// interval width
num_itervals = 6; %// number of intervals

%// Get matches for each interval and sum them within each interval for the counts
out = sum(bsxfun(@eq,ceil(LineData(:)/interval),1:num_itervals))
```

Output -

```
LineData =
     1     2     3     4     6    11    12    16    31    34    45
out =
     5     3     0     2     1     0
```

---

Assuming that the last interval would be the one holding the max of input data, you can try out a `diff` + `indexing` based approach too -

```
LineData = [ 1 2 3 4 6 11 12 16 31 34 45 ] %// Input
interval = 10; %// interval width

labels = ceil(LineData(:)/interval); %// set labels to each input entry
df_labels = diff(labels)~=0; %// mark the change of labels
df_labels_pos = find([df_labels; 1]); %// get the positions of label change
intv_pos= labels([true;df_labels]);%// position of each interval with nonzero counts

%// get counts from interval between label position change and put at right places
out(intv_pos) =  [ df_labels_pos(1) ; diff(df_labels_pos)];
```

Comment: I wonder if this would be faster/slower than histc when run over large numbers of iterations...

Comment: @Kris How big is `LineData`? What's its range (min and max)? Would you be running this counting problem within loops? `histc` is known to be pretty fast enough if you are only going to count, but you can test it out, right?

Comment: My experience is that ``histc`` is both just very fast and highly readable. Should you compare for speed, please include an ``accumarray``-version (which i don't expect to win in a 1d-histogram case): ``bins = floor(interp1(0:10:60, 1:7, LineData));`` followed by ``out = accumarray(bins', ones(length(LineData),1));``

Comment: @Nras Ran few tests and `bsxfun` definitely lags behind, but the `diff + indexing` based approach isn't too far behind `histc` based one.